# Find classpath maven is using for running testng testcase

Tags: maven-2, maven, maven-3, testng

what options to maven can I use to determine what classpath maven is running a testng test case with?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You didn't provide the Maven version, but at least in 3.x (and maybe also 2.x) you can run commands with the -X (debug) option. That way the Test Classpath is printed out before tests are run.

```
mvn test -X
```

Comment: This also works with maven 1.x

Also, I recommend that you grep the results to avoid having to search through the pages of output:

maven test -X | grep "maven.dependency.classpath"

Answer (score 9):

In general you can find the classpath that maven is using by using the built-in [maven dependency plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/index.html) and its [build-classpath goal](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/build-classpath-mojo.html).

If you want the classpath uses for compiling and running the test you need to select the `test` [dependency scope](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope). This scope is the default, but if you want to be explicit you can set it with `-DincludeScope=test`.

Other scopes include `runtime`, `compile`, `provided` and `system`.

Depending on how you want to consume the output you can play with the options `-Dmdep.outputFilterFile` and `-Dmdep.outputFile`. The `mdep.outputFilterFile` makes it easier to parse the output from a script and the `outputFile` option writes to a file instead which some tools can read directly.

Here are some examples:

```
$ mvn dependency:build-classpath -DincludeScope=test -Dmdep.outputFilterFile=true|grep 'classpath='
classpath=xxx.jar:yyy.jar
$ mvn dependency:build-classpath -DincludeScope=test -Dmdep.outputFile=cp.txt
$ cat cp.txt
xxx.jar:yyy.jar
```

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't format my response in my comment so submitting the grepped version here:

```
mvn test -X | grep "maven.dependency.classpath"
```